# All static members in a class that implements java.util.Observer?

Tags: java, design-patterns, observer-pattern

I want to make a class `R` which will observe all instances of class `S`, that is, I am using the observer-observable pattern. There is no need for having multiple instances of class `R`, I am sure of that. That is why I made all members of `R` as static. But, I am not sure if this is the right way to design the class. The `public void addObserver(Observer o)` method of `Observable` needs an object and not a static class. Is it okay if I create an instance of `R` only so that I can pass it to `addObserver` ? Does it violate the Observable-Observer pattern in any way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you don't need multiple instances of `R` (right now), you don't have to and shouldn't necessarily design `R` to consist of only `static` members. Program design could dictate the use of only one instance of `R`. Some would even suggest the use of the Singleton Pattern to enforce it programmatically.

> The public void addObserver(Observer o) method of Observable needs an object and not a static class

The phrase `static class` typically references an inner-class which is declared static to indicate that it can exist without an enclosing outer-class instance. I think you are using this phrase incorrectly.

> Is it okay if I create an instance of R only so that I can pass it to addObserver ?

Yes sure. Just because you've declared `R` in such a way that all members are `static` and thus belong to the class (as loaded by the ClassLoader), doesn't mean you can't construct and use as many instances of the class as you desire.

> Does it violate the Observable-Observer pattern in any way ?

So long as `R implements Observer`, no. In fact, it is not abnormal for the same observer to watch multiple observables.

Comment: Yes, I could use the singleton pattern for R. But I was wondering if there is any problem in making R all static and creating an R object and adding it as an observer to all S objects. Is there a problem in that ?

Comment: Edited to address some of the more specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

Nope does not violate.
Who knows maybe in the future you may have other observers.
You can still have static fields that are updated by non static methods.
So the state of the static fields are shared by all instances. (Mono state pattern)

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, avoid using static methods and fields. That is, if you can live with instance members only, do so. Static members are evil, sometimes necessary, but never desired.

Comment: Why are static members evil ?

Comment: For static variables, see `http://gbracha.blogspot.ru/2008/02/cutting-out-static.html`. Pure static methods (without access to static variables) can be tolerated in local environment, but are less practical in broader environment, because cannot be accessed via interfaces, and so are less flexible.

Comment: Unfortunately, he only describes the problem. He does not give code examples to show how the problems are caused. EXAMPLE - Not to mention the complexities that static initialization engenders: it can deadlock, applications can see uninitialized state, and unless you have a really smart runtime, you find it hard to compile efficiently (because you need to test if things are initialized on every use).